# How do I make construction heuristic phase assigns all entities in overconstrained planning?

Tags: optaplanner

As title says. I'm a developer new to optaplanner. Before I switched to overconstrained planning the CH phase worked correctly: here is CH assigning 21 entities as expected and LS was able to find an optimal solution (ignore the medium score level):

```
2021-10-01 12:26:07,933 [main] INFO  Solving started: time spent (3221), best score (-21init/0hard/0medium/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE), random (JDK with seed 0).
2021-10-01 12:26:10,664 [main] DEBUG     CH step (0), time spent (5955), score (-20init/0hard/0medium/-130soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@7c51782d {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@276b68af, index=47, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:12,924 [main] DEBUG     CH step (1), time spent (8215), score (-19init/-1hard/0medium/-3025soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@77bc2e16 {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@34d644b5, index=45, availability=2021-10-07T14:00-2021-10-07T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:14,137 [main] DEBUG     CH step (2), time spent (9428), score (-18init/-3hard/0medium/-3025soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@48e8c32a {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@50915d5, index=0, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:15,293 [main] DEBUG     CH step (3), time spent (10584), score (-17init/-3hard/0medium/-3164soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@20a7953c {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@276b68af, index=46, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:16,027 [main] DEBUG     CH step (4), time spent (11318), score (-16init/-4hard/0medium/-6098soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@57c00115 {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@34d644b5, index=42, availability=2021-10-07T14:00-2021-10-07T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:16,654 [main] DEBUG     CH step (5), time spent (11945), score (-15init/-6hard/0medium/-6098soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@411a5965 {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@50915d5, index=45, availability=2021-10-07T14:00-2021-10-07T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:17,267 [main] DEBUG     CH step (6), time spent (12558), score (-14init/-6hard/0medium/-6247soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@4fe533ff {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@276b68af, index=45, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:17,850 [main] DEBUG     CH step (7), time spent (13141), score (-13init/-7hard/0medium/-9221soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@5377414a {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@34d644b5, index=39, availability=2021-10-07T14:00-2021-10-07T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:18,541 [main] DEBUG     CH step (8), time spent (13832), score (-12init/-9hard/0medium/-9221soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@4e83a98 {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@50915d5, index=42, availability=2021-10-07T14:00-2021-10-07T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:19,182 [main] DEBUG     CH step (9), time spent (14473), score (-11init/-9hard/0medium/-9380soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@17aa8a11 {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@276b68af, index=44, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:19,758 [main] DEBUG     CH step (10), time spent (15049), score (-10init/-10hard/0medium/-9416soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@71b639d0 {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@34d644b5, index=45, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:20,332 [main] DEBUG     CH step (11), time spent (15623), score (-9init/-12hard/0medium/-12250soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@18a25bbd {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@63661fc7, index=45, availability=2021-10-07T14:00-2021-10-07T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:20,939 [main] DEBUG     CH step (12), time spent (16230), score (-8init/-12hard/0medium/-12419soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@5d5b9ecb {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@276b68af, index=43, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:21,499 [main] DEBUG     CH step (13), time spent (16790), score (-7init/-13hard/0medium/-15413soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@1ee27d73 {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@34d644b5, index=36, availability=2021-10-07T14:00-2021-10-07T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:22,085 [main] DEBUG     CH step (14), time spent (17376), score (-6init/-14hard/0medium/-15449soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@5e5aafc6 {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@50915d5, index=44, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:22,669 [main] DEBUG     CH step (15), time spent (17960), score (-5init/-14hard/0medium/-15628soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@542f6803 {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@276b68af, index=42, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:23,253 [main] DEBUG     CH step (16), time spent (18544), score (-4init/-15hard/0medium/-18662soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@5583098b {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@34d644b5, index=33, availability=2021-10-07T14:00-2021-10-07T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:23,833 [main] DEBUG     CH step (17), time spent (19124), score (-3init/-16hard/0medium/-18698soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@5807efad {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@63661fc7, index=43, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:24,427 [main] DEBUG     CH step (18), time spent (19718), score (-2init/-16hard/0medium/-18887soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@53a84ff4 {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@276b68af, index=41, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:25,010 [main] DEBUG     CH step (19), time spent (20301), score (-1init/-17hard/0medium/-18923soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@7ce85af2 {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@34d644b5, index=42, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:25,660 [main] DEBUG     CH step (20), time spent (20951), score (-19hard/0medium/-18953soft), selected move count (21120), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@316acbb5 {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@65130cf2, index=45, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:25,662 [main] INFO  Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (20953), best score (-19hard/0medium/-18953soft), score calculation speed (25027/sec), step total (21).
2021-10-01 12:26:25,961 [main] DEBUG     LS step (0), time spent (21252), score (-17hard/0medium/-24372soft), new best score (-17hard/0medium/-24372soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1000), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@5296ab0c {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@276b68af, index=47, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00} -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@34d644b5, index=41, availability=2021-10-05T14:00-2021-10-05T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:26,114 [main] DEBUG     LS step (1), time spent (21405), score (-15hard/0medium/-40094soft), new best score (-15hard/0medium/-40094soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1067), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@730794bb {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@276b68af, index=45, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00} -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@276b68af, index=46, availability=2021-10-01T14:00-2021-10-01T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:26,309 [main] DEBUG     LS step (2), time spent (21600), score (-13hard/0medium/-47776soft), new best score (-13hard/0medium/-47776soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1160), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@73ed094c {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@276b68af, index=46, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00} -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@276b68af, index=20, availability=2021-10-04T14:00-2021-10-04T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:26,471 [main] DEBUG     LS step (3), time spent (21762), score (-11hard/0medium/-65742soft), new best score (-11hard/0medium/-65742soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1145), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@3c37489b {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@276b68af, index=42, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00} -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@276b68af, index=0, availability=2021-10-01T14:00-2021-10-01T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:26,649 [main] DEBUG     LS step (4), time spent (21940), score (-9hard/0medium/-75202soft), new best score (-9hard/0medium/-75202soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1148), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@a386ccf {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@276b68af, index=41, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00} -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@276b68af, index=0, availability=2021-10-05T14:00-2021-10-05T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:26:26,832 [main] DEBUG     LS step (5), time spent (22123), score (-8hard/0medium/-75202soft), new best score (-8hard/0medium/-75202soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1172), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@144402f6 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@34d644b5, index=42, availability=2021-10-07T14:00-2021-10-07T22:00} -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@34d644b5, index=11, availability=2021-10-05T14:00-2021-10-05T22:00}}).
--------------------(omitting other steps)--------------------
2021-10-01 12:27:04,541 [main] DEBUG     LS step (347), time spent (59832), score (0hard/0medium/-42754soft),     best score (0hard/0medium/-42754soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1359), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@64047c70 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@276b68af, index=46, availability=2021-10-06T14:00-2021-10-06T22:00}} <-> optaplanner.domain.Allocation@3c37489b {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@276b68af, index=44, availability=2021-10-06T14:00-2021-10-06T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:27:04,635 [main] DEBUG     LS step (348), time spent (59926), score (0hard/0medium/-42754soft),     best score (0hard/0medium/-42754soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1365), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@68bb44fe {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@34d644b5, index=6, availability=2021-10-07T14:00-2021-10-07T22:00}} <-> optaplanner.domain.Allocation@62f89e6a {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@34d644b5, index=33, availability=2021-10-07T14:00-2021-10-07T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:27:04,709 [main] DEBUG     LS step (349), time spent (60000), score (0hard/0medium/-42754soft),     best score (0hard/0medium/-42754soft), accepted/selected move count (802/1086), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@7f77b1b0 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@34d644b5, index=13, availability=2021-10-07T14:00-2021-10-07T22:00}} <-> optaplanner.domain.Allocation@6f8a9b12 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@34d644b5, index=39, availability=2021-10-07T14:00-2021-10-07T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:27:04,709 [main] INFO  Local Search phase (1) ended: time spent (60000), best score (0hard/0medium/-42754soft), score calculation speed (11876/sec), step total (350).
2021-10-01 12:27:04,712 [main] INFO  Solving ended: time spent (60000), best score (0hard/0medium/-42754soft), score calculation speed (15115/sec), phase total (2), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE).
```

After switching to [nullable planning variable](https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.11.1.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#nullablePlanningVariable), medium score level has a constraint that penalizes for every unassigned entity. This is log from solving the same problem instance to which optplanner couldn't find an optimal solution:

```
2021-10-01 12:39:29,144 [main] INFO  Solving started: time spent (6235), best score (0hard/-21medium/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE), random (JDK with seed 0).
2021-10-01 12:39:33,797 [main] DEBUG     CH step (0), time spent (10892), score (0hard/-20medium/-130soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@7c51782d {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=47, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:39:36,698 [main] DEBUG     CH step (1), time spent (13793), score (0hard/-20medium/-130soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@77bc2e16 {null -> null}).
2021-10-01 12:39:39,032 [main] DEBUG     CH step (2), time spent (16127), score (0hard/-20medium/-130soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@48e8c32a {null -> null}).
2021-10-01 12:39:40,857 [main] DEBUG     CH step (3), time spent (17952), score (0hard/-19medium/-269soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@20a7953c {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=46, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:39:41,878 [main] DEBUG     CH step (4), time spent (18973), score (0hard/-19medium/-269soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@57c00115 {null -> null}).
2021-10-01 12:39:42,586 [main] DEBUG     CH step (5), time spent (19681), score (0hard/-19medium/-269soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@411a5965 {null -> null}).
2021-10-01 12:39:43,354 [main] DEBUG     CH step (6), time spent (20449), score (0hard/-18medium/-418soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@4fe533ff {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=45, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:39:44,007 [main] DEBUG     CH step (7), time spent (21102), score (0hard/-18medium/-418soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@5377414a {null -> null}).
2021-10-01 12:39:44,633 [main] DEBUG     CH step (8), time spent (21728), score (0hard/-18medium/-418soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@4e83a98 {null -> null}).
2021-10-01 12:39:45,251 [main] DEBUG     CH step (9), time spent (22346), score (0hard/-17medium/-577soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@17aa8a11 {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=44, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:39:45,898 [main] DEBUG     CH step (10), time spent (22993), score (0hard/-17medium/-577soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@71b639d0 {null -> null}).
2021-10-01 12:39:46,485 [main] DEBUG     CH step (11), time spent (23580), score (0hard/-17medium/-577soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@18a25bbd {null -> null}).
2021-10-01 12:39:47,151 [main] DEBUG     CH step (12), time spent (24246), score (0hard/-16medium/-746soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@5d5b9ecb {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=43, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:39:47,862 [main] DEBUG     CH step (13), time spent (24957), score (0hard/-16medium/-746soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@1ee27d73 {null -> null}).
2021-10-01 12:39:48,556 [main] DEBUG     CH step (14), time spent (25651), score (0hard/-16medium/-746soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@5e5aafc6 {null -> null}).
2021-10-01 12:39:49,193 [main] DEBUG     CH step (15), time spent (26288), score (0hard/-15medium/-925soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@542f6803 {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=42, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:39:49,781 [main] DEBUG     CH step (16), time spent (26876), score (0hard/-15medium/-925soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@5583098b {null -> null}).
2021-10-01 12:39:50,407 [main] DEBUG     CH step (17), time spent (27502), score (0hard/-15medium/-925soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@5807efad {null -> null}).
2021-10-01 12:39:51,168 [main] DEBUG     CH step (18), time spent (28262), score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@53a84ff4 {null -> ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=41, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:39:51,826 [main] DEBUG     CH step (19), time spent (28921), score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@7ce85af2 {null -> null}).
2021-10-01 12:39:52,372 [main] DEBUG     CH step (20), time spent (29467), score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft), selected move count (21121), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@316acbb5 {null -> null}).
2021-10-01 12:39:52,374 [main] INFO  Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (29469), best score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft), score calculation speed (19105/sec), step total (21).
2021-10-01 12:39:52,692 [main] DEBUG     LS step (0), time spent (29787), score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft),     best score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1000), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@41418e53 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=43, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}} <-> optaplanner.domain.Allocation@7f77b1b0 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=46, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:39:52,873 [main] DEBUG     LS step (1), time spent (29968), score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft),     best score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1213), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@c4d9e83 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=44, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}} <-> optaplanner.domain.Allocation@6f8a9b12 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=47, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:39:53,061 [main] DEBUG     LS step (2), time spent (30156), score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft),     best score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1503), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@7b174491 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=45, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}} <-> optaplanner.domain.Allocation@d464e23 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=41, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:39:53,270 [main] DEBUG     LS step (3), time spent (30365), score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft),     best score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1535), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@7f77b1b0 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=43, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}} <-> optaplanner.domain.Allocation@41418e53 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=46, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:39:53,457 [main] DEBUG     LS step (4), time spent (30552), score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft),     best score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1532), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@c4d9e83 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=47, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}} <-> optaplanner.domain.Allocation@6f8a9b12 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=44, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:39:53,605 [main] DEBUG     LS step (5), time spent (30700), score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft),     best score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1548), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@2957f567 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=42, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}} <-> optaplanner.domain.Allocation@7b174491 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=41, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
--------------------(omitting other steps)--------------------
2021-10-01 12:40:22,649 [main] DEBUG     LS step (367), time spent (59744), score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft),     best score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1455), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@d464e23 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=43, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}} <-> optaplanner.domain.Allocation@41418e53 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=41, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:40:22,731 [main] DEBUG     LS step (368), time spent (59826), score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft),     best score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1545), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@2957f567 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=42, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}} <-> optaplanner.domain.Allocation@c4d9e83 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=44, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:40:22,812 [main] DEBUG     LS step (369), time spent (59907), score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft),     best score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1535), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@7b174491 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=45, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}} <-> optaplanner.domain.Allocation@7f77b1b0 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=46, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:40:22,890 [main] DEBUG     LS step (370), time spent (59985), score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft),     best score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/1525), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@6f8a9b12 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=47, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}} <-> optaplanner.domain.Allocation@41418e53 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=43, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:40:22,905 [main] DEBUG     LS step (371), time spent (60000), score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft),     best score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft), accepted/selected move count (189/293), picked move (optaplanner.domain.Allocation@c4d9e83 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=42, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}} <-> optaplanner.domain.Allocation@d464e23 {ResourceTimegrain{resource=optaplanner.domain.Resource@668ea404, index=41, availability=2021-10-08T14:00-2021-10-08T22:00}}).
2021-10-01 12:40:22,905 [main] INFO  Local Search phase (1) ended: time spent (60000), best score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft), score calculation speed (18451/sec), step total (372).
2021-10-01 12:40:22,906 [main] INFO  Solving ended: time spent (60000), best score (0hard/-14medium/-1114soft), score calculation speed (16769/sec), phase total (2), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE).
```

Observation:

- CH didn't assign all entities which also affects LS (I guess since it is optional).
- CH had pointless steps (assign null -> null)

How do I make sure that all entities are assigned?

Answer (score 0):

The step ("assign null -> null") is not pointless. It shows OptaPlanner making a decision to keep something null. And it made that decision, because it was the decision that, of all the possible decisions, resulted in the best possible score. (Otherwise that decision wouldn't have been made.)

Most likely, assigning to non-null values would have broken a hard constraint - and OptaPlanner avoided that by assigning null. OptaPlanner behaves as expected here - you say you have more important concerns than nullity, and OptaPlanner respects your choice. (Nullity is only a medium constraint, while some other constraints are hard and therefore more important.)

If you wish to have all variables assigned, do not make them nullable.

Alternatively, design heavily weighted hard constraints for situations where unassigned variables are a problem. (But how would that differ from just not having them nullable in the first place?)